# How to add MKAnnotation to realm

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, realm

I am trying to add a MKAnnotation to Realm.

Here are my objects and what i tried:

```
class pins: Object {
    @objc dynamic var pin: MKAnnotation!
}

struct pin {
    static var pin: MKAnnotation!
}
```

I added my statics to a function and used realm.beginWrite() etc to add the annotations.

error:

> Thread 1: "Property pins.pin is declared as Optional,
> which is not a supported managed Object property type.

If any one knows how to store a MKAnnotation in Realm or knows what I'm doing wrong please let me know :D.

Comment: Sure - MKAnnotation is not a support Realm property so therefore it cannot be managed by Realm. See [Supported Property Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/data-types/supported-property-types/#std-label-ios-supported-property-types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MKAnnotation is not a supported Realm property so therefore it cannot be managed by Realm. See [Supported Property Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/data-types/supported-property-types/#std-label-ios-supported-property-types).

So the way to work with MKAnnotations is to break it down into objects (aka primitives) that Realm *can* manage; strings, numbers, etc.

MKAnnotation is a protocol so we would first need an object to store that data

```
class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var phone: String!
    var name: String!
    var address: String!
    var image: UIImage!

    convenience init(lat: Double, lon: Double, phone: String, name: String, addr: String, image: UIImage {
       let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
       self.coordinate = coord
       self.phone = phone
       etc
    }
}
```

and store your latitite and longitude in Realm as a Double.

One option is to use a Realm objects that contains the coordinate data

```
class MyCoords: Object {
   @objc dynamic var lat = 0.0   //or @Persisted var lat = 0.0 Realm 10.0
   @objc dynamic var long = 0.0
   @objc dynamic var phone = ""
   etc
}
```

Then read in the those objects and instantiate your MKAnnotation objects based on that data.

```
let myCoordResults = realm.objects(MyCoords.self)

for coord in myCoordResults {
   let annotation = MyAnnotation(lat: coord.lat, long: coord.long...
   // do something with the annotation
}
```